# template does not render even when condition is true

Tags: lightning-web-components, template

I have a tabset in my html, inside a template with a if:true={condition}.
This is the code:

```
<template if:true={dealSelected}>
<lightning-tabset variant="scoped">
    <lightning-tab label="Aprobadas" onactive={changeStatusTabDeal} data-status="approved">
        <c-paginator if:false={noItemResults} total-pages={totalPages} current-page={currentPage} onchange={changePageML}></c-paginator>
        <template for:each={itemResults} for:item="item">
            <c-item-with-promotions key={item.sf_id} seller-id={selectedSellerId} item={item}></c-item-with-promotions>
        </template>
    </lightning-tab>
    <lightning-tab label="Pendientes" onactive={changeStatusTabDeal} data-status="pending_approval">
        <c-paginator if:false={noItemResults} total-pages={totalPages} current-page={currentPage} onchange={changePageML}></c-paginator>
        <template for:each={itemResults} for:item="item">
            <c-item-with-promotions key={item.sf_id} seller-id={selectedSellerId} item={item}></c-item-with-promotions>
        </template>
    </lightning-tab>
    <lightning-tab label="Rechazadas" onactive={changeStatusTabDeal} data-status="rejected">
        <c-paginator if:false={noItemResults} total-pages={totalPages} current-page={currentPage} onchange={changePageML}></c-paginator>
        <template for:each={itemResults} for:item="item">
            <c-item-with-promotions key={item.sf_id} seller-id={selectedSellerId} item={item}></c-item-with-promotions>
        </template>
    </lightning-tab>
</lightning-tabset>
```

this is also inside another if:true template, that correctly meets the condition in this case.

dealSelected getter:

```
get dealSelected(){
    return this.selectedPromotion?.type == 'DEAL';
}
```

The method that should render the template:

```
selectPromotionML(event){
    this.resetPaging();
    Array.from(this.template.querySelectorAll(`lightning-input[data-name="promotionbox"]`))
    .filter(box => box.dataset.boxid != event.target.dataset.boxid).forEach(box => box.checked = false);
    const promotionId = event.target.dataset.id;
    //const promotionType = event.target.dataset.type;
    this.selectedPromotion = this.promotions.find(prom => prom.id == promotionId);
    console.log(this.selectedPromotion);
    console.log('deal selected => ' + this.dealSelected);
    if(event.target.checked){
        if(!this.selectedPromotion.type == 'DEAL'){ //si selecciono deal, va a buscar los items active con el onactive del tab
            this.getItemsML();
        }
    }else{
        this.resetPaging();
        this.resetItems();
    }
}
```

"selectedPromotion" is a property in the component. Shouldn't assigning something to the property make the template render? I already checked if the promotions.find() function was returning something, and it does, and also checked if the "type" property of the object in question has the right value. I also tried decorating the property with @track (even if it shouldn't be necessary) and it didn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are correct that `@track` should not be needed.  The code I can see looks valid; check that you don't also have a `dealSelected` class member variable declared with `let` or `var` at the top of your class; this can mask a getter of the same name.

Comment: @JasonClark I don't have another property or variable declared called dealSelected, only the getter. That is the weird thing. If you know of any unexpected behavior with conditional templates and getters let me know!